# How to create a new dataset by comparing rows in R

Tags: r, join, merge

I've a large dataset of around 90 different csv files built in this format (each for every university):

```
University | ArticleCode | Pages | Authors | year | Citations ...
```

I've to come up with this dataset that sums the articles published in common by year.
The article is uniquely identified by the ArticleCode, so if two different datasets have the same code in the ArticleCode column it means that the article is published together.

```
University1 | University2 | year | number of articles in common |
```

How can I do it using R?

Comment: What defines an "article in common" -- shared author? Is there any way to share a minimal toy example to demonstrate what you want to happen? This is surely doable, but the question will be much easier to answer if you can make it more specific.

Comment: Thanks for the response. You are right, I was not clear about it, sorry. I edited the question, let me know if it is understandable or if you need more specifics. Thanks!

Comment: here I posted a new question, hope It's better :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72433173/finding-links-between-different-database-with-r

Answer (score 0):

There are more sophisticated ways to do this, but for most data like this I can imagine, a simple brute-force `tidyverse` approach should work fine, and should be straightforward to follow.

Suppose we have this list of University, ArticleCode, and year:

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(42)                        # included so your output will match mine
df <- tibble(
  University = sample(LETTERS[1:4], size = 15, replace = TRUE),
  ArticleCode = rpois(n = 15, lambda = 2),
  year = 2010 + ArticleCode %% 2)   # Assumes all articles have one year each, 
                                    #   so if we know the article we know the year
```

Note that in this case, University A is listed for Article 4 twice, in row 1 and again in row 9. This was intended to replicate the possibility that the data might have duplicate listings of the same university and article, e.g. perhaps for multiple authors.

```
> df
# A tibble: 15 × 3
   University ArticleCode  year
   <chr>            <int> <dbl>
 1 A                    4  2010
 2 A                    5  2011
 3 A                    0  2010
 4 A                    2  2010
 5 B                    2  2010
 6 D                    4  2010
 7 B                    1  2011
 8 B                    6  2010
 9 A                    4  2010
10 D                    0  2010
11 C                    2  2010
12 D                    1  2011
13 C                    4  2010
14 D                    2  2010
15 A                    3  2011
```

Let's say I only want to include unique University-article pairs, I can make a modified version of the data which de-dupes these and arranges them for easier visual review. Note that the repeated A-4 row has been removed. I have also specified here that I only care about Article, year, and University for the purpose of counting annual articles in common. I could join with the original data if I need to retrieve any of the other columns later.

```
df_distinct <- df %>% 
  distinct(ArticleCode, year, University) %>%
  arrange(ArticleCode, year, University)

> df_distinct
# A tibble: 14 × 3
   University ArticleCode  year
   <chr>            <int> <dbl>
 1 A                    0  2010
 2 D                    0  2010
 3 B                    1  2011
 4 D                    1  2011
 5 A                    2  2010
 6 B                    2  2010
 7 C                    2  2010
 8 D                    2  2010
 9 A                    3  2011
10 A                    4  2010
11 C                    4  2010
12 D                    4  2010
13 A                    5  2011
14 B                    6  2010
```

There are powerful tools for network analysis like `igraph` which could help with more complicated situations, but for relatively small data approach should be fine. (I am assuming for instance that there are not typically thousands of universities involved per paper; if there were, then each paper article would create more than a million rows, which could for enough articles run up against memory limits.)

I join the data to itself (based on ArticleCode and year), filter out self-matches, and count the pairings per year.

```
left_join(df_distinct, df_distinct, by = c("ArticleCode", "year")) %>%
  filter(University.x != University.y) %>%
  count(University.x, University.y, year, sort = TRUE)
```

The output tells us that the A-D / D-A pairing of universities in 2010 had the most articles in common: 3. We can see in the data they both worked on article 0, 2, and 4 that year. If we only wanted to see each pairing once, we could replace the filter with `filter(University.x < University.y) %>%` to ensure we only see A-D and not D-A.

```
# A tibble: 14 × 4
   University.x University.y  year     n
   <chr>        <chr>        <dbl> <int>
 1 A            D             2010     3
 2 D            A             2010     3
 3 A            C             2010     2
 4 C            A             2010     2
 5 C            D             2010     2
 6 D            C             2010     2
 7 A            B             2010     1
 8 B            A             2010     1
 9 B            C             2010     1
10 B            D             2010     1
11 B            D             2011     1
12 C            B             2010     1
13 D            B             2010     1
14 D            B             2011     1
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That's really really helpful! Actually, I've 90 different csv for each university, if I merge them into a single dataframe like supposed by you I'd have something like 1.3M rows. I also published a new question adding additional informations and requirements if you would like to try to answer I would appreciate a lot.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72480210/how-to-obtain-a-incidence-matrix-with-grouping-in-r