# Finding links between different database with R - Network Analysis

Tags: r, networking, graph, merge

I have to do a **network analysis** starting from a database of approximately **90** different csv files, **each** refers to an institute and every row of the dataset represent a scientific article published by the institute.

Its organized like this (simplifying):

`Article.Code | Authors | Pages | Research.Categories | Year | Citations | etc…`

The aim is to study the grade of collaborations amid Institutes based on the number of articles published together, since every article has a unique code of identification, if we find two rows in two different databases with the **same ArticleCode** it means that the institutes had a collaboration for the publication and studies referred to the article.

Since is my first time ever using **R** I’ve encountered different problems in order to achieve :

- A database that contains the number of articles published in common between two institutes by year, with a separation of the total number of articles per Research Areas.

`InstituteName1 | InstituteName2 | year | #ArticlesInCommon | ResearchArea1 | ResearchArea 2 |…`

- Another issue that I’ve encountered is about defining the Research Area (5 in total) of an article since every article could have a combination of different research categories (here a link to better understand https://images.webofknowledge.com/images/help/WOS/hp_research_areas_easca.html )

I’m pretty sure that I’ve to insert a new column for each file and filling it with the name of the institute. The final scope is to have a graph of the network of collaborations between institutes and then analyze it, I've already seen that R offers packages that consent to do that.

---

Since the institutes are approximately 90, if I want to analyze every single collaboration between them in couple I’ve to analyze (and do steps in R) something like 4000 connections.

C(90,2)=  90!/(90-2)!2!

If I spend just 3 minutes for doing the steps and processing the dataset in R I’ll spend 200 hours!
I’m sure that exists some way to do it more efficiently and faster :’)

Comment: It is not at all clear what your question is.  It looks like there are two or three questions at least ( database design, research categorization and performance optimization ).  Can you choose what question you want answered and state the question clearly.  It always helps to describe what you have tried so far and how the results differ from what you want.

Comment: I see your point, and I agree with you, there are multiple requests in the post. I wanted to point out the multiple difficulties that I encountered. If I would have posted just the "database design problem" maybe someone could have answered me but I'd still have the "optimization problem". So I though that someone could tell me how to start from the database design from the beginning of the work in order to optimizate the time that I'd spend for the further work. I just starded a few days ago and I'm trying to merge two database in order to obtain the articles in common between 2 istitutions.

Comment: Please post a single question, clearly stated,

Comment: There seems to be an error in the description of the input.  You will need a field specifying the name of the institute publishing each article.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Tried to do it better and more clear here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72480210/how-to-obtain-a-incidence-matrix-with-grouping-in-r

Answer (score 0):

Your database will need two tables.

```
Table 1: Input
Fields 
ArticleCode 
InstituteName 
Research.Categories  ( This nay have to be split: cat1, cat2, ... , catmax )
Year
```

and

```
Table 2: Collaboration
InstituteName1
InstituteName2
year 
#ArticlesInCommon
ResearchArea1 
ResearchArea2 
…
ResearchArea5
```

You may need a third table to handle the relationship between "research areas" and "research categories".  You have not described this clearly enough for me to make a concrete suggestion.