# How to obtain a incidence matrix with grouping in R

Tags: r, merge, dataset, match, bigdata

I have to study collaboration network between Scientific Institutes through the number of papers and articles published together. Every article has a unique code that identifies the specific article. If two (or more) institutes have the same **ArticleCode** in their database that implies a collaboration amid them in the publication of that article.

Here's how the dataset is organized:

```
Intitute name | ArticleName | ArticleCode | Area | Pages | NumberofCitations | ...
```

I have around 90 institutes in total, so **90 csv files** like this up here. The result that I have to reach is a single table in which I have this information:

```
Institute#1 | Institute#2 | TotArticles | TotArea#1 | TotArea#2 | TotArea#3 |...
```

So I need for **each** couple of Institute that has collaborated, their name, the total number of articles together released (TotArticles) and their subdivision in Areas in the other columns (5 in total: *Arts & Humanities;Life Sciences & Biomedicine;Physical Sciences;Social Sciences;Technology*).

At the beginning I thought it could be done by merging the csv by ArticleCode but I soon realized that if I want to analyze all the possible combinations between all the institutes I'll have to repeat the merge steps 4000 times... a huge waste of time.

Maybe it could be done faster if I merge in one unique csv the total of publications of every single institute and then operate on it in order to obtain the final table. Adding all the rows of the 90 csv I'll obtain something like 1.300.000 rows, don't know if it could be technically possible to operate on it.

Below an example.

Hope I exposed the problem clearly enough, otherwise just let me know with a comment.

---

Starting from something like this...

```
Institute | ArticleCode | Area             | Pages | ...  
In.AAA    | articleX    | Arts & Humanities| 90    | ...
In.AAA    | articleP    | Technology       | 10    | ...
In.BBB    | articleZ    | ...              | 907   | ...
In.BBB    | articleX    | Arts & Humanities| 90    | ...
In.CCC    | articleF    | Arts & Humanities| 89    | ...
In.DDD    | articleP    | Technology       | 10    | ...
In.DDD    | articleX    | Arts & Humanities| 90    | ...
```

to this:

```
Institute#1 | Institute#2 | TotArticles |Arts & Humanities | TotTechnology
In. AAA     | In.BBB      | 1           | 1                | 0         
In. AAA     | In.DDD      | 2           | 1                | 1           
In. BBB     | In.DDD      | 1           | 1                | 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the Institute column to a numeric factor, and then join the table on itself with a non-equi join, using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[, Institute:=as.factor(Institute)]
result = dcast(
  df[df[, Institute2:=Institute], on=.(ArticleCode, Institute>Institute2), nomatch=0],
  Institute+Institute2~Area,fun.aggregate = length
)[, TotArticles:=rowSums(.SD), .SDcols = -c(1,2)]
```

Output:

```
   Institute Institute2 Arts & Humanities Technology TotArticles
1:    In.AAA     In.BBB                 1          0           1
2:    In.AAA     In.DDD                 1          1           2
3:    In.BBB     In.DDD                 1          0           1
```

Input:

```
structure(list(Institute = c("In.AAA", "In.AAA", "In.BBB", "In.BBB", 
"In.CCC", "In.DDD", "In.DDD"), ArticleCode = c("articleX", "articleP", 
"articleZ", "articleX", "articleF", "articleP", "articleX"), 
    Area = c("Arts & Humanities", "Technology", "...", "Arts & Humanities", 
    "Arts & Humanities", "Technology", "Arts & Humanities"), 
    Pages = c("90", "10", "907", "90", "89", "10", "90")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

#### Update (6/6/22)

OP now wants to add an additional column, say `Year`, that indicates the year of the article, and additionally separate rows by that value. Only two small changes are needed:

1. Add `Year` to the Left-Hand-Side of the formula in dcast
2. Expand the columns that are excluded from the rowSums from `c(1,2)` to `c(1:3)` (i.e. from the first two columns to the first three columns

```
setDT(df)[, Institute:=as.factor(Institute)]
result = dcast(
  df[df[, Institute2:=Institute], on=.(ArticleCode, Institute>Institute2), nomatch=0],
  Year + Institute+Institute2~Area,fun.aggregate = length
)[, TotArticles:=rowSums(.SD), .SDcols = -c(1:3)]
```

Output:

```
Key: <Year, Institute, Institute2>
    Year Institute Institute2 Arts & Humanities Technology TotArticles
   <num>    <fctr>     <fctr>             <int>      <int>       <num>
1:  2005    In.AAA     In.BBB                 1          0           1
2:  2005    In.AAA     In.DDD                 1          0           1
3:  2005    In.BBB     In.DDD                 1          0           1
4:  2006    In.AAA     In.DDD                 0          1           1
```

New Input:

```
structure(list(Institute = c("In.AAA", "In.AAA", "In.BBB", "In.BBB", 
"In.CCC", "In.DDD", "In.DDD"), ArticleCode = c("articleX", "articleP", 
"articleZ", "articleX", "articleF", "articleP", "articleX"), 
    Area = c("Arts & Humanities", "Technology", "...", "Arts & Humanities", 
    "Arts & Humanities", "Technology", "Arts & Humanities"), 
    Pages = c("90", "10", "907", "90", "89", "10", "90"), Year = c(2005, 
    2006, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2006, 2005)), row.names = c(NA, -7L
), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: How should I command if I had ad addictional column in the original dataset that indicates the year of publication od the article and I need the same table in output as you did but with a column with the year. So each collaboration between 2 institutes could have multiple rows one for each year they collaborated?

Comment: you would just make two small changes.. see my edit.